# Using the formula for electric energy confusion $W = P * t$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, electric-circuits, power

I have this example question:

A low energy lamp has the label 230V, 15W.
It gives about the same amount light as a regular lamp at 75W.
How much energy do we save by using the low energy lamp if it's lighten up 1000 hours?

Can I calculate this by doing:

```
15W * 1000h = 15000Wh
```

and the same for 75W and then just subtraction. But that's not important right now.

or is that incorrect? If it's correct, can you explain it to me a little in-depth why it is! I'm a bit confused by how this works. Should I answer in Wh? Did we save 60000Wh or what(75000Wh - 15000Wh)? Haha.

Answer (score 1):

Considering this is likely high school physics, you can indeed write
$$
W = P \cdot t
$$
and plug in your values for power and time, respectively. The "power saved" (I don't really like the term) by switching to a LED or flourescent energy saving lamp is then indeed the difference between $W_1$ and $W_2$. Also, since this is a homework and exercise question, please label it as such.

Comment: Well, thanks. I'm in middle school(I think you say in English). This is for a test I'm studying for, and I'm trying to understand how it works. Could you explain more about the result? Is it ok to write it in Wh, and is it in the correct format? Like 50000Wh?

Comment: Consider reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilowatt_hour if the concept of (Kilo)Watt hours confuses you. But it's rather easy. The lamp uses energy (in the form of electric current) to emit light. The amount of energy is normally given in Joule, but, when looking at Joule in SI base units, you can write Joule as Watt hours. It's important in physics that the units in an equation match up, that is, to have [something in Joule] = [something else in units that are equal to Joule].

Comment: And yes, your answer should be something along the lines of "the power saved by using an energy saving lamp is X Wh". Though you might want to recheck the 50000...;)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if it's the Wh that confuses me, it's the whole answer thing. Thanks though.

Comment: Ohh.... I see. Thanks!  It isn't 50kWh? Oh?

Comment: I think I understand this now! Thanks. But still not why 50000 wouldn't be correct :D

Comment: Well, the conventional lamp uses 75W over 1000 hours, that is, 75 kWh (as per your initial question). The energy saving lamp uses 15W over 1000 hours, that is, 15 kWh. The difference between those is not 50 kWh, but a bit more. I just won't give you the answer *that* easily ;)

Comment: I'm stupid xD It's 60kWh... Haha! It's late here in Sweden, I blame that.